# Logical statements: $A+B+C=A+B+C+AB+BC+AC$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $A,B, C$ be logical statements.
>   Then: 
>   $A+B+C=A+B+C+AB+BC+AC$

Prove it without a table.

---

My attempt:

$$A=A\cdot(1+B+C)$$
$$B=B\cdot(1+A+C)$$
$$C=C\cdot(1+A+B)$$
$$\implies A+B+C= A+AB+AC+B+AB+BC+C+BC+AC$$
$$\implies A+B+C=A+B+C+AB+AB+BC+BC+AC+AC$$
$$\implies A+B+C=A+B+C+AB+BC+AC$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. it is completely correct.

You could have shortened it a bit by writing

$$A+B+C+AB+BC+AC = A(1+B+C) + B(1+C) + C $$ $$
\stackrel{1+x=1,1x=x}{=}A+B+C$$

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, if you are using Monotone laws of Boolean algebra or [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence), we can write$:$
\begin{align}
&\hspace{3ex}A+B+C\\
&=A+AB+B+BC+C+CA\tag*{Absorption law}\\
&=A+B+C+AB+BC+AC\tag*{Commutative law}
\end{align}